# keep initial weights with dynamic paint

Tags: weight-painting, dynamic-paint

I have a plane with hand drawn vertex weights and I'm trying to dynamically paint onto it during animation. The problem is that if I set the dynamic paint vertex output to the same vertex groups with my hand drawn weights on, then rather than getting modified by the dynamic paint, my hand drawn weights get completely overwritten at the start of the animation.

Is there a way to keep the existing weights and just modify them dynamically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a different weight group for the dynamic paint. Then mix these two groups with the Vertex Weight Mix modifier. This way you can choose how your weights will be mixed with great possibilities.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that's the solution.